# Points on a 2D plane

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a set of points (x,y) in a 2-d plane, which are guesses of a particular unknown point (x',y'), how do find the best estimate of (x',y') using the set of points given.  This is an interview question I found on an online forum. Can somebody please suggest something? My take: take the average of all x values, take the average of all y values. Find the standard deviation for the x values, and the standard deviation for the y values. Then the x is estimated by its mean, and the y by its mean.

Is there a better or more precise or standard way to do this?

Comment: This question belongs in a stats forum, but not on SO.

Comment: The answer really depends on knowing the distribution of the points. The more information you can provide, the better will be your answer. Without that information, you can use things like an average or median, but an average of some ilk actually presumes some information about that distribution of points. Are the noises iid & Gaussian? If so, then an average is indeed the right thing. In other cases, medians or trimmed means might be more robust methods.

Comment: @woodchips: even in the Gaussian case with known variance, averaging is not the "best thing to do" (in the usual sense) when the number of points is greater than 3. See [Stein's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_example). You are perfectly right in the fact that this belongs to a stats forum, and not to SO.

Comment: @AlexandreC. - Of course, this just makes my point - that this question is not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but I think you're looking for the distance of the guesses from the reference point. Let's say, r is the reference point g is the guess.

```
dx = (rx - gx)
dy = (ry - gy)
distance squared = dx ^ 2 + dy ^ 2
```

The smallest distance squared should be the closest hit.

Comment: can you please explain what is gx? Also, can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad This is equivalent to finding mean.

Answer (score 0):

First you can find average of point, after that remove some points which are very far from average, again take average, and continue this till there isn't any very far node (from average) in each step you can change the meaning of far distance.